# Set custom start point in Image.alpha_composite

Tags: python, image-processing, transparency, alpha

im trying to use Image.alpha_composite to overlay 2 images with thieir edges overlap.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OORv8.jpg)

```
Image.alpha_composite(iamge1,image2)
```

But the start point for ovelaping in Image.alpha_composite is top right corner of the image. Is there any way to change it for custom (x,y), or is there similar method that i can use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since there's no origin argument I believe the only way is to create a new image and copy the old one to the point you want to act as the origin.